# Is there a way to load latex package BEFORE unicode-math when using R markdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

Suppose we are using R markdown to creat a beamer presentation

```
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
date: "date"
documentclass: beamer
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
    theme: metropolis
    keep_tex: yes
---
```

By default, it will use `unicode-math` to set up the math fonts, which I'm totally fine.
However, if I try to include `mathtools` package in the preamble, there is a warn saying that `mathtools` should be load BEFORE `unicode-math`. I checked the .tex file, and find that everything in the includes:in_header: will appear AFTER the load of `unicode-math` package.

**Question: How to let R markdown (or Pandoc?) load certain latex package BEFORE it loads unicode-math?**

includes:in_header: or header_includes not work.

Comment: Which packages from `mathtools` do you need exactly? Beamer by default already loads most of them. Do you actually need `mathtools`?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz what do you mean by which packages? `mathtools` is A package, not a collection of packages.

Comment: Mathtool is a package which basically loads a bunch of packages + some other stuff. Do you need it or just some of the packages it loads?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I need it. For example, I need `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`

Comment: The easiest way might be to make a copy of the `beamer_presentation` rmarkdown/pandoc template and add the package there.